# Ordering of Strings returned from Json path query and used in a Junit Assertion

Tags: java, string, junit, hashset, jsonpath

Something of a newbie question:

I have to assert against an address on a page.  I am querying the API firstly to get the address and I am then asserting against it on the webpage.

Here is my method to get data from API:

```
   public Set<String> getPlaceAddressLinesFromApi(String addressId) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://app.ard.domain.local:8084/addresses/" + addressId);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        String json = content.toString();
        Set<String> addresslines = new HashSet<String>();
        addresslines.add(JsonPath.read(json, "$.location.postalAddress.lines[0]").toString());
        addresslines.add(JsonPath.read(json, "$.location.postalAddress.town").toString());
        addresslines.add(JsonPath.read(json, "$.location.postalAddress.county").toString());
        addresslines.add(JsonPath.read(json, "$.location.postalAddress.postcode").toString());
        return addresslines;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

When I use the method in an assertion I get an error:

```
assertEquals(addressLinesFromApi, addressLinesFromWebsite, "The address displayed and address returned from api do not match");

Expected :TownHouse, Exeter, Devon, EX15 2LE
Actual   :[Exeter, Devon, EX15 2LE, TownHouse]
```

How can I order the String's returned from the `JSON` to use in the assertion?

How can I remove the '[]' brackets?

Comment: can you paste your assertion?

Comment: Sure, I have now added

Comment: what's type of `addressLinesFromWebsite`?

Comment: It's a String, obtained through a WebElement  = element.getText();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your `addressLinesFromWebsite` by `,\\s*` to `HashSet` and compare:

```
assertEquals(addressLinesFromApi, new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(addressLinesFromWebsite.split(",\\s*"))), "The address displayed and address returned from api do not match");
```

Comment: Thanks - this works! I'm not familiar with Regex - could you explain how it works?

Comment: `,\\s*` means that match start from "," with appending zero or one or multi spaces.

Comment: There is a [regex tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions), You can learn more details from it

Comment: If this answer has solved your problem, please accept it.